# Why attach method returns null in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables `posts`,`tags`, and a pivot table `post_tag`.

`post_tag` table is :

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id |   post_id   | tag_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |      2 |
|  2 |           2 |      2 |
|  3 |           3 |      1 |
|  4 |           4 |      1 |
|  5 |           4 |      3 |
|  6 |           5 |      3 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

I have this in `Post` model :

```
class Post extends Model {  
    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag'); 
    }
}
```

And this in `Tag` model :

```
class Tag extends Model {       
    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Now in my Controller I'm trying to insert a record to the pivot table `post_tag` :

```
$post = Post::find(4);
$post_tag = $post->tags()->attach(2);
return $post_tag //it returns null
```

So, I need to get details of created record in pivot table, but `$post_tag` contains `null`!

How can I get the details(like `id ,...`) of last inserted record on the pivot table?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check [**`sync()`**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L805) method which returns an array of attached ids as well:

```
$post = Post::find(4);
$post_tag = $post->tags()->sync([2], false);
var_dump($post_tag['attached']);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
}
```

Be aware that a `false` parameter should be passed as the second argument to avoid detaching all other rows.

Answer (score 3):

The attach method doesn't return any thing, this is why you are getting null. To check if record was inserted successfully you would need to make another call to DB. It is similar to Delete method. Check [this](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_attach) for reference to attach method.

Comment: Yes you're right. But I think it's so bad that `attach` method doesn't return anything!